# Team Explorer Everywhere Work Item Query Check-in Policy

Tags: team-explorer-everywhere

I have setup a Work Item Query Check-in Policy in Team Explorer Everywhere but the query on the policy is being ignored, a check-in is allowed regrades of the work item you select.

I am using Team Explorer Everywhere Version 14.0.2 and TFS 2012 Update 3.

Does anyone have any ideas why the query is being ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have met below demands.

> Check-in policies that you define by using Team Explorer Everywhere
>   **only apply when you check in by using the Team Foundation Server plug-in for Eclipse or the Cross-platform Command-Line Client for Team
>   Foundation Server.** If you use another client, such as Team Web
>   Access or Team Explorer in Visual Studio, these policies do not apply.
>   Similarly, policies that you define by using Team Web Access or Team
>   Explorer in Visual Studio are not applied when you check in by using
>   the Team Foundation Server plug-in for Eclipse or the Cross-platform
>   Command-Line Client for Team Foundation Server.
>
> Source Link:[Configuring Check-in Policies (Team Explorer
>   Everywhere)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475890(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have created the policy in Team Foundation Server plug-in for Eclipse and am check-in via this when it fails. Incidentally if I create the same policy in Visual Studio and check-in via visual studio it works perfectly.

Comment: Did this work on a new created project? And also try to restart your Eclipse.

Comment: Have tried restarting Eclipse that makes no difference, it fails across multiple different computers.